# How to bold text while stay in a current section

Tags: html, reactjs

I have different sections on a website (all on the same page), and I also have a navigation bar that is always fixed at the top. I want when I go to stay in the section the text in the navigation bar to be bold, indicating that I am there, how can I make this possible?

These is the structure of the App:

```
export default function Main() {
 return (
  <div className="App relative">
    <NavBar fixed />
    <Home />
    <Purpose />
    <WhoWeAre />
    <FinancialSolutions />
    <Products />
    <ComercialPartners/>
    <SocialMedia />
    <Footer />
  </div>
  );
}
```

All of the components are in diferents files, and every one has their id tag. And the navbar has every section except the Footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Intersection observer for that. The intersection observer detects which element is currently on the screen.
Your case is tricky because you need to detect which way you are scrolling first. Because when you scroll down you want to say that you are in a section when the title of the section disappears at the top of the page. But when you scroll up you want to say that you are in the section when the title of the section appears at the top of the page.
So first we need to detect the direction of the scrolling and then detect which element is appearing or disappearing.

The hook return refs. You have to give the ref to elements in your code that you want to detect if they are intersecting or not.
Like that:
`<h2 ref={ref1}>TITLE</h2`

Your main component needs to implement `const [idVisible, setIdVisible] = useState("");` Then pass `idVisible to your navbar to determine which one should be highlighted.

The other useState `const [clickedSection, setIsClickedSection] = useState(false);` may not be needed. It depends if when you click on a section in your navbar it navigates to the section on the page. If it is the case then you need to pass the setIsClickedSection function to your navbar too. When you click on a link you need to set it to 'true'. The reason is that navigating to a section trigger scrolling and will create weird results.
It is a little complicated. Took me a day or 2 to arrive at this.
If your last section is small it may never intersect at the top of the screen. One way to deal with that is to use to detect if you reach the bottom of the page and then `setIdVisible` to the last section of the page.

This is the hook that I made for a similar purpose:

```
export const ShowSectionHook = (clickedSection: boolean, setIsClickedSection: (value: boolean) => void, setIdVisible: (value: string) => void, window: Window, lastSectionId: string, firstId?: string) => {


    const ref1 = useRef(null);
    const ref2 = useRef(null);
    const ref3 = useRef(null);
    const ref4 = useRef(null);
    const ref5 = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        //Scroll listener to determine the scroll direction
        const threshold = 0;
        let lastScrollY = window.scrollY;
        let scrollDir = "";

        const updateScrollDir = () => {
            const scrollY = window.scrollY;

            if (Math.abs(scrollY - lastScrollY) < threshold) {
                return;
            }
            scrollDir = (scrollY > lastScrollY ? "scrolling down" : "scrolling up");
            lastScrollY = scrollY > 0 ? scrollY : 0;
        };

        const onScroll = () => {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(updateScrollDir);
        };

        window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

        //interjection observer to detect if the element is on the page
        const element1 = ref1.current;
        const element2 = ref2.current;
        const element3 = ref3.current;
        //create one for each section you have

        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            ([entry]) => {
                if (scrollDir === "scrolling down" && entry && !entry.isIntersecting && !clickedSection) {
                    setIdVisible(entry.target.id);
                }
                if (scrollDir === "scrolling up" && entry && entry.isIntersecting && !clickedSection) {
                    setIdVisible(entry.target.id);
                }

                setIsClickedSection(false);
            },
            {
                root: null, //viewport
                rootMargin: "0px",
                threshold: 1, //this means that the element get detected when 100% of the card is visible
            })

        if (element1) {
            observer.observe(element1);
        }
        if (element2) {
            observer.observe(element2);
        }
        if (element3) {
            observer.observe(element3);
        }

        return () => {
            observer.disconnect()
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
        }

    }, [clickedSection, setIdVisible, setIsClickedSection, window, lastSectionId, firstId])

    return {ref1: ref1, ref2: ref2, ref3: ref3}
}
```